# Фронт енд не обрабатывает запрос с бек енда. Insomnia обрабатывает запрос с бек енда

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express

Всем привет.
Есть get запрос в бек едне на получение пицц по категории и сортировки по цене и т.д. С фронта передается категория и сортировка в виде стейта. (0,1,2,3) и т.д. Используется монго дб, таблица имеет поле category и поля rating,price,title для сортировки. Через Insomnia все работает прекрасно, значит проблема в фронте.Другие запросы по проще на получение всех пицц работает с фронта. Помогите, спасибо. Запрос обрабатывается фронтом но при любой категории возращает пустой массив.
**

**Фрон енд**

**

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Categories from "../components/Categories";
import Sort from "../components/Sort";
import PizzaBlock from "../components/PizzaBlock/PizzaBlock";
import PizzaSkeleton from "../components/PizzaBlock/Skeleton";
const Home = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [categoryId, setCategoryId] = React.useState(1);
  const [sortType, setSortType] = React.useState(0);

 
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4444/categorysort", {
        params: {
          category: categoryId,
          sortBy: sortType,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setItems(response.data);
        setIsLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Ошибка при получении данных:", error);
      });
  }, [categoryId, sortType]);
  // categoryId here, so,useEffect, have to follow
  // for this state,if this state will chanched, then we fire request(useEffect).
  // console.log(categoryId, sortType);
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="content__top">
        <Categories
          value={categoryId}
          onClickCategory={(id) => setCategoryId(id)}
        />
        <Sort sortValue={sortType} onClickSort={(id) => setSortType(id)} />
      </div>
      <h2 className="content__title">Все пиццы</h2>
      <div className="content__items">
        {isLoading
          ? [...new Array(10)].map((_, index) => <PizzaSkeleton key={index} />)
          : items.map((obj, index) => <PizzaBlock key={index} {...obj} />)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Home;
```

**Бек енд**

```
    export const getCategorySort = async (req, res) => {
  const { category, sortBy } = req.body;

  let query;

  if (category === 0) {
    // Если "category" равно '0', получаем все пиццы без фильтрации по категории
    query = Pizza.find({});
  } else {
    // Иначе, фильтруем по указанной категории
    query = Pizza.find({ category });
  }

  if (sortBy === 0) {
    query = query.sort({ rating: -1 });
  } else if (sortBy === 1) {
    query = query.sort({ price: -1 });
  } else {
    query = query.sort({ title: -1 });
  }

  try {
    const pizzas = await query.exec();
    res.json(pizzas);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
};
```

**Таблица монго Дб**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const PizzaSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    id: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    imageUrl: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    types: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    sizes: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    category: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    rating: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
export default mongoose.model("Pizza", PizzaSchema);
```

[image: Так выгдядит пример пиццы]

[image: Пустой массив с фронта]

Comment: В ответе(response) что приходит?

Comment: {data: Array(0), status: 200, statusText: 'OK', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}  Пустой массив

Comment: Значит такие данные летят с бэка. Дебажте. Что уходит с фронта, как обрабатывается и так далее